# what is the difference between setState() and BLoC pattern in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to collecting difference points between only `setState()` and BLoC Pattern.

& just collected one difference point is that:

1.)`setState()` method always used with `Stateful Widget` But BLoC pattern can be  used with both Widget  `Stateless` or  `Stateful`.

So my question is, what is the main difference between both And which is better and reliable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searched a lot , I found the major difference ,

Basically`setState()` is very easy to use and it give Immediate feedback  but it does not help to achieve our goals means UI presentation and business logic , all are in same class therefore code does not look clean and high quality means code looks messy in form that's why code maintenance might be become challenging in the future if application grows.
But

In bloc pattern, all declared in different class means UI presentation is defined in different class and business logics defined in different therefore code looks clean and high quality.

NOTE: if application is small then you are free to use `setState()` but if application is big then do not use `setState()`

Answer (score 3):

`setState((){})` is used to manage local state in the same `StatefulWidget` and it's child .

`BLoC pattern` is used to manage global state .

[image]

in this example if you want to pass data from `WIDGET B2` to `WIDGET A` : 
if you used `StatefulWidget` you should pass data from `WIDGET B2` to `WIDGET B1` to`WIDGET B` to `WIDGET A` . 
but if you used BLoC pattern or other way to manage global state you pass data from `WIDGET B2` to `WIDGET A` directly .

```
[Provider][is recommended by flutter team , you can use it to manage global state]
```

Answer (score 2):

How you transfer data from child or descendant widget to parent widget? That's why people use state management tools as an alternative of setState. Setstate is effective when you do sth only local state otherwise we need global or app-level state.

Answer (score 1):

They are different things.

- `setState((){})` is a function called inside a StatefulWidget to modify its state and then rebuild it.
- BLoC is a state management pattern. It can also refer to [the package](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) that helps implement this pattern in a clean way.

FYI, [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is the state management solution put forward by the Flutter team. You can learn more about state management [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).

Comment: But both modify app's state and rebuild state. so what is the Difference?

Comment: State management solutions also uses `setState((){})`.They do it through the builder widgets you put around the widgets that need global state (like StreamBuilder, or Consumer for provider). And what you said below about separating business logic from the UI code is true.